# Are the different situations overriding each other? minecraft

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am trying to create a mod in Minecraft that uses a lucky block with a `TileEntity`. I have the `TileEntity` call a class with the different situations that can happen from the lucky block. However, the different situations in the class seem to override each other or spawn two situations but only one is collectable. Google doesn't help and I don't want this lucky block to be like other blocks.

Code:

The different situations:

```
public void startPickingMinimal(World w, BlockPos pos){
    switch(w.rand.nextInt(3)){
        case 0:
            for(int y = 0; y < 4; y++){
                BlockPos upPos = new BlockPos(pos.getX(), pos.getY() + y, pos.getZ());
                w.setBlockState(upPos, Blocks.diamond_block.getDefaultState());
        }
    break;
        case 1:
            EntityLightningBolt bolt = new EntityLightningBolt(w, pos.getX(), pos.getY(), pos.getZ());
            w.spawnEntityInWorld(bolt);
    break;
        case 2:
            for(int fy = 0; fy < 5; fy++){
                ItemStack n_gapple = new ItemStack(Items.golden_apple);
                ItemStack gapple = new ItemStack(Items.golden_apple, 1, 1);
                EntityItem enNGapple = new EntityItem(w, pos.getX(), pos.getY() + fy, pos.getZ(), n_gapple);
                EntityItem enGapple = new EntityItem(w, pos.getX(), pos.getY() + fy + 1, pos.getZ(), gapple);
                w.spawnEntityInWorld(enNGapple);
                w.spawnEntityInWorld(enGapple);

        }
    break;
}
```

TileEntity code (the code that invokes the situations):

```
@Override
public void update() {
    if(enabled){
        counter--;
        if(counter == 0){
            worldObj.setBlockToAir(getPos());
            new LuckyBlockItems().startPickingMinimal(worldObj, getPos());
         }

    }
}
```

Comment: It would be best if you put the code in here, rather than link to the code in a shared Google doc.

Answer (score 0):

You're FIRST setting the block to air... then you expect the block to be still there to do stuff for you. It doesn't work that way.

Do your setBlockToAir as last or in an overriding run(the diamond blocks for example)

also, `!world.isRemote()` is your friend

Otherwise you get a spawn event on the client(which is not collectible) and a different one on the server(which is collectible)